# Using Windows 8 with Bootcamp?

Tags: windows-8-preview, bootable-media

I am trying to install Windows 8 using Bootcamp on an Apple machine. I need a bootable CD. Does the bootable CD have to be the size of the ISO image or can it be smaller (since it only contains the installer)?

If it does not in fact have to be the size of the ISO image, what's the minimum required size of the CD I insert into my drive to create a bootable CD? (i.e. the minimum size of a bootable USB is 8GB)

Answer (score 0):

It's not fully supported by Apple yet, ie: no native bootcamp drivers. So trackpad, wifi etc. do not work out of the box. I'd wait.

Comment: First of all - this doesn't relate to the asker's question at all (SuperUser is not a forum, please limit answers to actual answers). Second, This is not entirely true. The multi-touch drivers for the trackpad are the only driver that has been widely seen as "not working." I installed windows 8 on my Macbook Pro with the Windows 7 drivers. Video, wifi, audio, screen and keyboard backlight brightness all work fine. Only trackpad gave issues, and there's [a workaround](http://xdumaine.com/2012/09/01/windows-8-macbook-pro-trackpad/) to fix it, albeit without multi-touch.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 8 ISOs we've got are less than 3.5GB, so a single layer 4.7GB writable DVD should be fine.